# Issue installing web3 using npm

Tags: npm, ethereum, web3js

I am trying to install web3 using npm but getting the issue, its w3b300 that's not there any more

Following this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@mvmurthy/full-stack-hello-world-voting-ethereum-dapp-tutorial-part-1-40d2d0d807c2)

Here's what logs say

[image]

Comment: Probably because there is no such thing as web300. The command is using `web3@0.20.2`

Comment: There is, it worked like couple of months ago and please dont downgrade the question if you dont know the answer.

Comment: Aside from the fact I know the answer, I also know the tutorial. And if you check the image in the link for dev setup, you will clearly see your typo. If you don’t want to trust the information provided to you from people on this site, you’re free to investigate on your own.

Comment: Where's the typo, can you please identify, i haven't seen any

Comment: `npm install web3@0.20.2`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the issue was new webjs library makes use of async calls a lot.

Digging into documentation helped me solve the issue. Just make sure whcih version you are on and read documentation accordingly.